# cin to linked list core dumped

Tags: c++, linked-list, cin

I'm having a problem with `cin` in c++. I'm trying to `cin` a text file to the program, and then put all the words etc. in a linked list, but I'm having a problem with the `temp->next` part, the core gets dumped.

```
string x = ""; //ordet blir lagret her
string y = stopwords_c;
string tegnfjern = stopchars_c;

int antallOrd = 0;

struct ord{
string ordet;
int ant;
};

struct node{
node* next;
ord o;
};

int main(){

    node* ord = new node;
    node* temp = ord;


while(cin >> x)
{
    if(temp == NULL)
    {
        temp->o.ant++;
        temp->o.ordet =x;
        antallOrd++;
    }

    else
    {
        while(temp->next != NULL && temp->o.ordet != x)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        if(temp->o.ordet == x)
        {
            temp->o.ant++;
        }

        else
        {
            if (cin >> x)
            {
                temp->next = new node;
                temp = temp->next;
            }

            temp->o.ordet = x;
            temp->o.ant++;
        }

        temp = ord;                
    }
}
```

Comment: The declaration of your node struct would help, too.

Comment: `if (temp == NULL) temp->ANYTHING` -> boom.

Comment: @crashmstr what do you mean by this? thanks for the help btw.

Comment: @user3311743 see the answer that [sleepy42](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21789273/1441) added. If a pointer is `NULL` you should not do anything with `->`, that is a null pointer exception. This is a big reason you check for NULL.

Comment: @crashmstr do you mean struct node{ node* next = null}?

Comment: @user3311743 initializing a point to `NULL` or `nullptr` is good, but you should not try to do anything like `node->next` when `node == NULL`. If you have written Java, you should be familiar with the concept. Even though it looks like the code is not hit with your expanded sample, it is still very wrong.

Comment: @crashmstr okey, but it is not where the problem is.. if I make an int i = 0; and use if(i<200) where the next node is made, the program works. why is that?

Comment: Where do you insert that `if (i < 200)`? And an additional point is that you read in a second word: first of all you read a word in the loop condition into `x` and then (if the word is not found in the list) you read a second word into `x` (and the previous content is dropped) and ignore the word previously read. So it also might happen that there is nothing more to read and your program might crash.

Comment: I don't know if you have to use that linked list. If so ignore this comment. If not you also could use a `std::map` with a string as keyvalue and an integer as datavalue: the integer then counts how often your string was already entered. That might not be the fastest implementation (as you are using a `string` as key), but it would work...

Comment: @sleepy42 instead of if(cin >> x) {temp->next = new node; temp = temp->next.. the point of the program is to count the occurences of different words. the words dont get dropped.

Comment: yeah, Ive already made one with a map, but in the second assignment we cant use STL, just datastructures that you make yourself or arrays.

Comment: But you read a first in the loop condition into `x`. Then you check the list and determine that the word is not already contained in your list (that's where you reach the `if (cin >> x)`). At this point you know that the value of `x` before evaluating the `if` condition does not exist in the list. Now you evaluate the `if` condition and during evaluation you read a new value into `x` and you did neither create a node for the old `x` value nor increase any counter. So the old value of `x` was just ignored.

Comment: @sleepy42 ive tried to remove the 'if(cin>>x)' compleatly and leave 'temp->next = new node; temp = temp->next;' to see if it works without. but it doesent.. the only way i get it to work is if I have an if sentence there.. how do I check if the 'cin' reaches the last char?

Comment: And I would set `ant` to zero in the default constructor (you also would have to add one) to avoid `ant` having any random/garbage values when such a new struct is created.

Comment: What happens when you omit the if?

Comment: @sleepy42 im not sure what that means

Comment: Add a default constructor to your struct `ord` that sets the value of `ant` to 0.

Answer (score 1):

You first check if `if(temp == NULL)` and if it is so you nevertheless want to access members of it. That cannot work. If `temp` is `NULL` you have to create new node struct and add it to the list (depending on what `temp` exactly represents). So some more information about the node structure and the list would be great.

**EDIT**
Let me summarize what you should do:

- Add default constructors to both structs that initialize `ant` to `0` and `next` to `NULL` (or `nullptr` if you can use the new standard).
- As already mentioned several times: get rid of the code that tries to access members of a nullptr.
- Just drop the `if (cin >> x)`. You don't need it as you ignore the old value that was read into `x` in the loop condition (and furthermore if `cin >> x` fails you overwrite an existing entry). But only the condition itself - not the code executed inside it: you definitly need that code as it creates the new node to store the new word. Draw a picture with boxes and arrows if you don't know how that could happen.

If you do all that it should work - at least it then worked for me. Furthermore:

- I hope you know that there is some kind of sentinal in this list: the element created with `node* ord = new node;` always remains in the list and counts all occurences of the string `""`. You must pay attention to that (especially when freeing the elements in the list).
- I would merge both structs into one single struct as it makes the code more readable (at least in my opinion).
- Don't forget to free your list properly!

Comment: I like the comment of @ crashmstr

Comment: added some more code.. the problem is not in if(temp == NULL), the problem is in if(cin >> x) temp->next = new node; part.. if I quote thaat out, the program runs

Comment: @user3311743: Dereferencing a null pointer is nevertheless wrong.

Comment: Im really new to this. only coded in Java before.. what should I do with the dereferencing?

Comment: It also might help to initialize the `next` pointer to `NULL` in the constructor of struct node (so you would have to add one).

Comment: @user3311743 if you have coded in Java before, you should be familiar with not accessing objects set to NULL.